# windows server 2008 vs ubuntu 11

Tags: windows-server-2008, ubuntu

I am working on implementing a custom server application that should be capable of handling a very large volume of traffic.

I am aware that this type of question has been asked a lot, but I haven't been able to find a good answer. What I'm really looking for is for a server with given specs which OS will be able to handle a larger traffic faster and more reliably. I do not care about rights management or any other features.

I am fairly good with both platforms, and so I would like to pick the OS with better performance on a clean install, and with nothing else running.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't been able to find an answer, because it is off topic. Read the [faq]

Comment: If you picked a platform at random, and heavily optimized for that platform, I bet you would get the similar results if you went the either way.  Yes, there may be exceptions, but the exceptions are exceptional.  With no details, there is no way to say for certain.  Why not just try it and see.  For example, if your application did a  lot of stuff with the filesystem you would need to compare the performance of NTFS on the Windows side against the half-dozen different filesystems available under Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

This question is really off topic and probably will be closed soon... I'd ask like this if I were you:

- This specific application
- Approximately this specific clients connecting
- Approximately this specific network transfer load for each client expected

etc... Then you can answer me with O.S.'s and network's limitations...

Because if your scenerio is something like serving a database to 1000 transaction in a short period of time then your 7200-RPM HDD, just one 1-Gbps NIC and a 32-bit O.S would not be enough...

Answer (score 0):

You don't provide enough information to make that kind of assessment.  There are any number of considerations as to why you'd use X over Y.